# I can't center positioned widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I must use `Stack` and `Positioned` widgets for my layout but also I need to make sure my widgets are centered so I can't use left, right.

```
  Widget _body() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          child: _animation(),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 300,
          child: Text(
            "Centered Text",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        Positioned(
          top: 350,
          child: Text(
            "Second Centered Text",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The text widget should be centered.

Comment: I have updated my 2nd answer, that will also center your 3rd widget now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Align` in your second widget.

```
Widget _body() {
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        left: 0,
        child: Text("Text here"),
      ),
      Align(
        child: Text(
          "Centered Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: It throws an exception The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following children

Comment: I just used your code and replaced `Positioned` with `Align`. Are you sure you did things correctly?

Comment: Now it works but I want to add a third widget with align. It's not working.

Comment: Can you update your post, I will let you know how to do that.

Comment: I updated with old code (not fixed code to not ruin the original question)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `Align`, no problem here is what you can do then.

```
Widget _body() {
  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center, // you need this
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Text("Text here"),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 300,
        child: Text(
          "Centered Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 350,
        child: Text(
          "Second Centered Text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Actually I can't say i don't want to use or I want to use this approach or another. If there is an approach that allow me to don't write hard coded pixel values like align, i prefer that. With this approach i just add top: 300 , top: 350 etc.

Comment: OK, I will give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to centre all the elements , you can use Alignment.center in stack widget , if you want centre particular widget , you can add left : 0 and right : 0 , surprisingly it worked for me.

```
Widget _body() {
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      left: 0,
      child: _animation(),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 300,
      left : 0, //Add this to centre your text
      right : 0, //Add this to centre your text
      child: Text(
        "Centered Text",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
      ),
    Positioned(
      top: 350,
      left : 0, //Add this to centre your text
      right : 0, //Add this to centre your text
      child: Text(
        "Second Centered Text",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
```